# ¿Por qué no autoriza la IP? (IPTables en PHP)

Tags: php, iptables

Bueno primero que nada quería solicitar ayuda sobre un código que uso para hacer una whitelist básica, lo que hace es registrarse y al loguearse te autoriza la IP, pero el código de iptables no hace ningún efecto y sigues viendo off al dedicado por más que tu IP sea "autorizada".

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ ?>
    <li><p class="navbar-text"><strong>Bienvenido!</strong> Has iniciado sesión como <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></strong> y tu IP ha sido autorizada, deberías ver al servidor en línea (<strong>samp.sampmega.com:7777</strong>).</p></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    <?php               
    $ip_address = getUserIP();
    echo exec('sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s ' . $ip_address . ' -j ACCEPT');
    echo exec('sudo iptables -A INPUT -s ' . $ip_address . ' -j ACCEPT');
?>
```

El problema que tengo son las dos líneas de "iptables", ayuda por favor.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

necesitas agregar el flag -d para la direcciones de afuera del firewall.

> **nota:** debes hacer un restart del los servicios del `firewall`
>   **nota 2:** php tiene los  mismos permisos que el usuario `www-data` por lo general o puedes ejecutar `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` para ver bajo que usuario se esta ejecutando
>   **nota 3:** el comando sudo requiere el `passsword` del usuario root.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ ?>
    <li><p class="navbar-text"><strong>Bienvenido!</strong> Has iniciado sesión como <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></strong> y tu IP ha sido autorizada, deberías ver al servidor en línea (<strong>samp.sampmega.com:7777</strong>).</p></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    <?php               
    $ip_address = getUserIP();
    echo exec('sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp  -d ' . $ip_address . ' -j ACCEPT');
    echo exec('sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s ' . $ip_address . ' -j ACCEPT');

?>
```